# Can anyone tell me why does Chrome tell it is Mozilla and Safari also?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-detecting

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_nav_all

I get

> Browser CodeName: Mozilla
>
> Browser Name: Netscape
>
> Browser Version: 5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1
>
> Cookies Enabled: true
>
> Platform: Win32
>
> User-agent header: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1

Comment: Are you trying to *do* something with this information, or just asking out of curiosity? The very short version is that useragent information like this is a giant mess of lies to get around bad browser sniffing, indicate compatibility/similarity, etc. But if you're actually trying do something, there's probably a better way to test for browsers. It's pretty unusual now and even discouraged to do actual browser sniffing like this, in part because of the problem you're seeing.

Comment: I'm asking for curiosity

Comment: The majority of User Agents now settle on including "Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically it started because some websites used to sniff the user-agent to tell what browser someone was using so they could block browsers that they thought wouldn't work with their websites. Specifically, websites were blocking Internet Explorer because it didn't offer as many features as Netscape Navigator. Instead of simply building a website that works across browsers, webmasters chose to just block IE completely. To get around that, Internet Explorer started to put Mozilla in their user-agent (with "compatible" in parenthesis).

Another reason is some browsers share the same rendering engine. For example, both Safari and Chrome use the webkit rendering engine. Firefox and SeaMonkey both use gecko. As a result they will both have pieces of their user-agent which will match and/or mention the other browser.

[This article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/12/history-of-the-user-agent-string/) has a good summary of user-agent history in much more detail.

Comment: http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

Answer (score 2):

Almost every browser says it's Mozilla, meaning it is (more or less) compatible with Mozilla rendering engine.

Comment: Yes! This link shows the most common ones in realtime: https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/